# Exact same WebGL code renders differently on different devices

Tags: floating-point, webgl, precision, vertex-shader, fractals

I'm fairly new to shaders, just started playing with them in VisionsOfChaos for Android around a year ago. I implemented my 4D fractal viewer in it (as far as I know, a completely new approach, which is most close to the Julibrot renders, but using a fake3D ismoetric space, as I'm not that good at complex maths, raytracing and shaders yet).

Then as a web-developer, I realized there's now WebGL, and ported the code to JavaScript with a basic UI. I also tried to optimize it for mobile, and used it more on my Android phone than on my PC or laptop. Since then, I improved the UI/UX a lot, and the site is now live at https://psyklon.com/pf4d

However, I noticed there are some formulas that render differently on my PC and my phone. I don't think the whole code is relevant here, as it must be something with floating-point precision. Here's the example with the relevant parts:

```
precision highp float;

uniform vec2 u_canvasSize;
```

...more uniforms

```
vec2 cmul(vec2 a, vec2 b) {
    return vec2(a.x * b.x - a.y * b.y, a.y * b.x + a.x * b.y);
}
vec2 cexp(vec2 z) {
    return exp(z.x) * vec2(cos(z.y), sin(z.y));
}
vec2 cpowc(vec2 z, vec2 a) {
    return cexp(cmul(a, clog(z)));
}

void main() {
```

...variable declarations, then one loop for the isometric step, and one for the 2D iteration. Inside that:

```
        if (i > u_maxIter || escaped) break;
        
        z = cpowc(cpowc(z, c), cpowc(c, z));
        
        if (length(z) > u_bailout) {
            count += 1.0;
            escaped = true;
            break;
        }
```

Here's the above example on images (note the outer part of the disc):
[image: Windows laptop]

[image: Android phone]

**So my question is, is it possible to work around this, or this is a bug/feature(?) of GPUs handling floats differently, and I can't do anything about that?**
As it is now more like an art than a code project of mine (of course I have many ideas to improve, but also like to just explore), it would be great to maximize the odds that every user will see the exact same image when they load it up from the gallery.

Parameters for the example:

```
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
```

Comment: At minimum, the results of transcendental functions like `sin`, `cos`, `exp`, `log`, `atan` are not going to be bit-wise identical across platforms, because these functions do not typically produce correctly-rounded results for all inputs (generally considered too costly in terms of processing time). Combine this with the fact that various interesting deep zooms into the Mandelbrot set operate at the limit of floating-point precision and some of the resulting artifacts are bound to be different.

Comment: So you say it's impossible to use the GPU for what it's supposed to do: fast and precise calculations? For me, highp means "high precision", not "some shitty estimation that differs on every single chip". Sigh... :(

Comment: Sorry, I can't dig trough that 120 pages right now to see what "is specified", but if I understand correctly, GPUs were never intended to be precise, just fast? I can do the same calculations with JS (on CPU), but that would be very far from real-time. Long story short: is it impossible to normalize the outcome on GPUs?

Comment: Ok, I will look at it later on my PC, my phone just downloaded the pdf and I can't search in it. But still, my question is not answered, as I don't use double precision at all. If my phone support highp float, it shoud render the same image desn't it? I read a few similer questions here on SO, but they used lowp or mediump, and the accepted answer was that to change it to highp. In my scenario I already did that.

Comment: I still don't see how this is related to my question. I already knew highp is a keyword, which is I think was derived from two words, high and precision. Following this logic (correct me with a quote if i'm wrong), this is not the best name for it when such unpredictable outcomes are common.

Comment: @BalázsVarga The IEEE-754 floating-point standard (adhered to by both CPUs and GPUs) only mandates correctly rounded basic operations. Just like the results of transcendental functions are *not* bitwise identical between different CPU math libraries, this also applies to GPU math libraries. While most GPUs do support double-precision computation in hardware (e.g. all of NVIDIA's have done so since about 2008),  I don't know whether use of WebGL's `precision highp` is guaranteed to map to IEEE-754 `binary64` a.k.a. double precision. That is why I asked.

Comment: [4.7.2. Precision Qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#precision-and-precision-qualifiers)

Comment: Yes, I ported it to the browser but the shader code is untouched, I just have to set up a different UI.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it has some useful informations! :)

Comment: The correct spec for WebGL 1 shaders would be [the GLSL ES 1.0 Spec](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf)(page 33). Precision qualifiers only apply on mobile OpenGL ES contexts to begin with, on desktops they're not used. Furthermore they don't define a fixed precision but just a minimum range. Ensuring bitwise parity across all platforms is indeed impossible especially when including mobile GPU and driver combinations.